# jquery css div images don't appear

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have this request for when the document loads:

```
   jQuery( window ).load(
        function(){

        $('#container img').animate({"opacity": 1});

        $('#container img').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": .5 });
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": 1 });
        });

            setTimeout(
                function(){
                    window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
                },
                50
            );

        }
    );
```

This if statement which I will add to when I get something working correctly:

```
function touchMove(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if ((event.touches.length === 1) && (swipeDirection === 'down') && (swipeLength >= 90) && (swipeLength <= 120)) {
    curX = event.touches[0].pageX;
    curY = event.touches[0].pageY;
    ('1.png').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": '1'

        });
```

And this CSS:

```
<style>
        #container {
            background: transparent;
            left: 5px;
            top: 20px;
            position: relative;
            border: 1px dotted #ddd;

        }
 </style>
```

And then this in the body:

```
<div id="swipe-frame" class="swipe-element" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'swipe-frame');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event);" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);" style="width:100%; height:100%; background: transparent; -webkit-user-select: none;padding-top:128px;">
</div>

    <div id="container">
    <img src="1.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="2.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="3.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="4.png" alt="image" />
    <img src="5.png" alt="image" />
</div>
```

Because I am trying to load 5 images on top of each other to make it appears as though they are one image. They are grayed out when the document loads. Then as the user slides their finger across the image the images are animated to their normal state. But nothing is appearing. Does anyone know why? http://tinyurl.com/62hakh2  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `height:100%` from the `#swipe-frame` div, since this will make the div occupy the whole screen and the `#container` div will be just after it.

Comment: When I remove the 100% from the height and width nothing appears. Just a white screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load the images on top each other, you'll need to apply a style to them, not just their container.  Try:

```
 #container img {
    background: transparent;
    left: 5px;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;    
    }
```